# InvalidCursorName : Django Admin error referencing wrong column in ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I've setup a relationship using django's `ForeignKey` against 2 unmanaged tables like so:

```py
class Product(BaseModel):
    publish_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=40)
    # this works:
    associated_country = models.ForeignKey('geonames.Countryinfo', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='published_country', blank=True, null=True)
    # this doesn't:
    associated_continent = models.ForeignKey('geonames.Continentcodes', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='published_continent' blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'product'

class Continentcodes(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    geoname_id = models.ForeignKey('Geoname', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'geoname_continentcodes'

class Countryinfo(models.Model):
    iso_alpha2 = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2)
    country = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    geoname = models.ForeignKey('Geoname', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    neighbours = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['country']
        managed = False
        db_table = 'geoname_countryinfo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'
```

When I go to edit an entry in the django admin page for 'Products' I see this:

> InvalidCursorName at /admin/product/6/change/ cursor
> "_django_curs_140162796078848_sync_5" does not exist
>
> The above exception (column geoname_continentcodes.geoname_id_id does
> not exist LINE 1: ...ntcodes"."code", "geoname_continentcodes"."name",
> "geoname_c...
> ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column
> "geoname_continentcodes.geoname_id"

It looks like it's trying to reference **geoname_continentcodes.geoname_id_id** for some reason. I have tried adding `to='code'` in the ForeignKey relationship, but it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Additionally, the `associated_country` relationship seems to work just fine if I comment out the `associated_continent` field. The `associated_continent` is the column that is giving some problem.

Here is some more context about what the table looks like in the database:
[image]

Comment: I don't get the problem. You have a 1-to-1 (FK) named `geoname_id` in your `Continentcodes` model, to which Django will automatically append another `_id` suffix when computing the column name. Have you tried renaming the field name to `geoname` as you did in the `Countryinfo` model?

Comment: @Selcuk my question then is, how do you not have django automatically append an _id to the column name? I would like to resort to renaming the field as a last option since I would have to directly connect to our db in production to do this it seems.

Comment: Have you tried adding `db_column='geoname_id'` like you did with some other fields?

Comment: @Selcuk my understanding is this specifies the column in the source table (products) for the foreign key. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Comment: also, renaming the field from geoname_id to geonameid does not work

Comment: I still don't follow. What column name should it be? Can you post the database schema of your table for the `Geoname` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the '_id' as the suffix is the fix. In this case `geoname_id` changed to `geoname` fixes this. Why? I have no idea. Django is doing something behind the scenes that is not clear to me. Here is the updated model:

```py
class Continentcodes(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # remove '_id' as the suffix here
    geoname = models.ForeignKey('Geoname', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'geoname_continentcodes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Django adds _id to the end to differentiate between the object and the id column in the table, geoname_id will return the table id where as geoname will return the object.